# Set selected values to Multi select Spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner, multi-select

I am developing an android application, where I need to give multi select spinner with week/month names. User will select multiple days from spinner and send it to server. If he want to edit the selected dates he should be able to edit, this is my requirement.
For this I have got code for Multi select Spinner Which I have posted below.

Now the problem is, When User wants to edit the selected days, I am getting the selected days from server successfully, but I am unable to display them as selected in spinner.
I have tried  `spinner.setSelecetd(list)` but no luck. I am getting Null pointer Exception.
Please see my below code and help me...

MultiSelectSpinner Code

```
public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends AppCompatSpinner implements
    DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {

public interface OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener{
    void selectedIndices(List<Integer> indices);
    void selectedStrings(List<String> strings);
}
private OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener listener;

String[] _items = null;
boolean[] mSelection = null;
boolean[] mSelectionAtStart = null;
String _itemsAtStart = null;

ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;

public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);

    simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
}

public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
}


public void setListener(OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
        mSelection[which] = isChecked;
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.TimePickerTheme);
    builder.setTitle("Please select!!!");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);
    _itemsAtStart = getSelectedItemsAsString();
    builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            System.arraycopy(mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection.length);
            listener.selectedIndices(getSelectedIndices());
            listener.selectedStrings(getSelectedStrings());
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            simple_adapter.clear();
            simple_adapter.add(_itemsAtStart);
            System.arraycopy(mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart.length);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
            "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
}

public void setItems(String[] items) {
    _items = items;
    mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
    mSelectionAtStart = new boolean[_items.length];
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
    Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
    mSelection[0] = true;
    mSelectionAtStart[0] = true;
}

public void setItems(List<String> items) {
    _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
    mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
    mSelectionAtStart  = new boolean[_items.length];
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
    Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
    mSelection[0] = true;
}

public void setSelection(String[] selection) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
        mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
    }
    for (String cell : selection) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
            if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {
                mSelection[j] = true;
                mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
        mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
    }
    for (String sel : selection) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
            if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {
                mSelection[j] = true;
                mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public void setSelection(int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
        mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
    }
    if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
        mSelection[index] = true;
        mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                + " is out of bounds.");
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
        mSelection[i] = false;
        mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
    }
    for (int index : selectedIndices) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
            mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                    + " is out of bounds.");
        }
    }
    simple_adapter.clear();
    simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
}

public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
    List<String> selection = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            selection.add(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

public List<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
    List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            selection.add(i);
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

private String buildSelectedItemString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean foundOne = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            if (foundOne) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            foundOne = true;

            sb.append(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean foundOne = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
        if (mSelection[i]) {
            if (foundOne) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            foundOne = true;
            sb.append(_items[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

I am getting selected Values from server like below

```
Jan,Jun,Sep
```

I converted them to List by using below code

```
List<String> result; 
 result=Arrays.asList(timeIntervaloptions.split(","));
```

Converted output is

```
[Jan, Jun, Sep]
```

Now I am trying to set this output to Spinner by using below code

```
 addEventRepeatWeekSpinner.setSelection(result);
```

When the above piece of code Runs, I am getting the below Error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at com.venkat.office.office.MultiSelectionSpinner.setSelection(MultiSelectionSpinner.java:173)
                                                 at com.venkat.office.office.executive.Main2Activity$4.onResponse(Main2Activity.java:644)
```

Line no 644 in Main activity is , `addEventRepeatWeekSpinner.setSelection(result);`

Any help would be very thankful!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
  public class MultiSpinner extends Spinner implements 
     DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener, 
      DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {

    private List<String> items;
    private boolean[] selected;
    private String defaultText;    
    private int position;
    public MultiSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MultiSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)                              {
            selected[which] = true;

        }else{
            selected[which] = false;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // refresh text on spinner
        StringBuffer spinnerBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        boolean someUnselected = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (selected[i]) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items.get(i));
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ");
            } else {
                someUnselected = true;
            }
        }
        String spinnerText;
        if (someUnselected) {
            spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString();
            if (spinnerText.length() > 2)
                spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 2);
        } else {
            spinnerText = defaultText;
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            new String[] { spinnerText });
        setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items, String allText, int position) {
        this.items = items;
        this.defaultText = allText;       

        this.position=position;
        // all selected by default
        selected = new boolean[items.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++){            
            selected[i] = true;                              
        }

        // all text on the spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] { allText });
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

And set adapter and call set items method

```
   String spinnerText="";
   List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(YourDto yourDto:DtoList){
    tempCategoryList.add(yourDto.getName());
    if(yourDto.isSelected()){
     spinnerText+=yourDto.getName()+",";
     }
   }

    if(spinnerText.equals("")){
         spinnerText="Select";
     }

     if (spinnerText.endsWith(",")) {
     spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 1);
      }   
   ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, 
   R.layout.textview_layout, tempList.toArray(new 
   String[tempList.size()]));

   myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_divider);
   holder.yourSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
   holder.yourSpinner.setItems(tempList, spinnerText,position);
```

May be this helps you!!!

Comment: Thanks fro answer!!! I am implementing my Logic Inside Activity not Adapter class, How do I get the position value?? can you explain me..???

Comment: If you are implementing from activity means don't use the position, just remove that parameter. The position parameter is used to only update the adapter values.

Answer (score 0):

Try add all in array list like this:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.addAll(Arrays.asList(timeIntervaloptions.split(",")));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Aj 27... I tried the way you said, but no luck.. Still I am getting the same error...    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array